# Marklogic - How to remove new line char issue in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to removing the new line character .

```
Sample Code.

    let $b := <root><title>Fees • Levies<?brk type="line"?>
    Other file</title></root>
    return replace($b//title/text(),'\n','')

Expected Output :
Fees • Levies Other file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options I can think of:

[fn:replace()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:replace)  - but you have to account for both possible chars

```
let $b := <root><title>Fees • Levies<?brk type="line"?>
    Other file</title></root>
return fn:replace(fn:data($b//title), '(\r?\n|\r)', '')
```

But this can leave you with extra whitespace depending on how it was created and formatted, Therefore, you may also prefer to clean up the whitespace and the newline at once using [fn:normalize-space()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:normalize-space)

```
let $b := <root><title>Fees • Levies<?brk type="line"?>
    Other file</title></root>
return fn:normalize-space(fn:data($b//title))
```

You may also note that I used fn:data(). This was out of habit. However, there is a great blogpost [here](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2011/06/text-fnstring-and-fndata/comment-page-1/) on the subject of text, string, data.

Comment: HI. Glad it worked. A note: I updated the post with a link related to my choice for fn:data()

Comment: I'd recommend normalize-space, or replacing line-ends with spaces. Otherwise words can get glued together..